# TFS build service produces a package with a reference to the wrong version of msshrtmi (should be 1.7, ends up referencing 1.8)

Tags: azure, msbuild

I just set up a continuous deployment build (using the azure TFS service a.k.a visualstudio.com) for my project, but it doesn't work right.  The build seems to be fine, and the deployment starts, but my worker role always recycles continuously.  My manual builds in Visual Studio deployed through the management portal work just fine.  When I remoted into one of the worker VMs to see what was going on, I found this in the event log:

```
An unhandled exception occurred. Type: Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException Process ID: 2488
Process Name: WaWorkerHost
Thread ID: 13
AppDomain Unhandled Exception for role MyProject.Worker_IN_1
Exception: An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudStorageAccount)' on type 'TemplateRepository'.
  at MyProject.Worker.WorkerRole.Run() in c:\a\src\MyProject\Dev\MyProject.Worker\WorkerRole.cs:line 383
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.StartRoleInternal()
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Implementation.Loader.RoleRuntimeBridge.<startrole>b__1()
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Inner Exception: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment' threw an exception.
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(String configurationSettingName)
  at MyProject.Worker.Core.Repositories.TemplateRepository..ctor(CloudStorageAccount account) in c:\a\src\MyProject\Dev\MyProject.Worker.Core\Repositories\TemplateRepository.cs:line 24
  at lambda_method(Closure , Object[] )
  at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()

Inner Exception: Could not load file or assembly 'msshrtmi, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
 0x80131040)
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.InitializeEnvironment()
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment..cctor()
```

It seems that for some reason, builds performed on the TFS build servers wind up with an incorrect reference to version 1.8 of msshrtmi, rather than 1.7 (which is what all my projects actually reference).  I tried adding an explicit reference of msshrtmi, and I also tried the suggestion found here (http://tomkrueger.wordpress.com/2010/07/27/azure-deployment-issue-after-upgrading-to-visual-studio-2010-and-net-4-0/) and neither one seemed to work.

Any other suggestions?

**update**: here's a link to my [cross-post on MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/azuretfs/thread/8fd9dbec-532d-4dea-865b-080beef45266)

Answer (score 1):

Could you be referencing 1.8 versions of the Azure assemblies?

The 1.8 version of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime references version 1.8 of msshrtmi.dll and will fail with this message if the target Azure environment does not have the dll.

Comment: This was my thought as well, but I checked all my references, and they all point to 1.7 (or 1.7.0.3).  Also, I can deploy just fine from my developer workstation, via publishing from visual studio or manually uploading a package.  Because of this I feel fairly certain that the issue is on the build server(s).